# QuartzDeadlineManager (Scheduler) inadvertently replaces configured TransactionManager

Tags: axon

Axon documentation is somewhat faulty at describing the nuances between `EventScheduler` and `DeadlineManager`, and in which scenario you have to use each one. In a trial by fire, I attempted to use `EventScheduler` in one of few `Saga`s implemented. I realized it does not trigger `@EventSourcingHandler` on Aggregate, so I was forced to change to a `DeadlineManager`. (Hint: this could be better described in documentation)

Now first challenge was to configure the DeadlineManager without any insight. Here is the final code I ended doing:

```
@Configuration
public class AxonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public DeadlineManager deadlineManager(
        final Scheduler scheduler,
        // Disregard "Could not autowire. No beans of 'AxonConfiguration' type found." complain from IntelliJ.
        // This class is an @Configuration, which is a @Component by itself.
        final org.axonframework.spring.config.AxonConfiguration configuration,
        final TransactionManager transactionManager,
        final Serializer serializer
    ) {
        return QuartzDeadlineManager.builder()
            .scheduler(scheduler)
            .serializer(serializer)
            .scopeAwareProvider(new ConfigurationScopeAwareProvider(configuration))
            .transactionManager(transactionManager)
            .build();
    }
}
```

As you may see, when using a reputable IDE, it complains that AxonConfiguration is not a Bean, so you have to live with the warning forever.

When I injected the `DeadlineManager` in my `Saga`, I've done this:

```
@Slf4j
@Saga
public class MySaga {
    static final Long DELAY_INITIALIZE = 60L;
    static final String INITIALIZE_DEADLINE_NAME = "MyInitialize";

    @Autowired
    private transient DeadlineManager deadlineManager;

    @Autowired
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;

    private String scheduleName;
    private String scheduleId;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "correlationId")
    protected void on(final ScheduleEvent event, @Timestamp final Instant eventInstant) {
        final Instant timerInitialize = eventInstant.plus(Duration.ofSeconds(DELAY_INITIALIZE));

        this.scheduleName = INITIALIZE_DEADLINE_NAME;
        this.scheduleId = this.deadlineManager.schedule(
            timerInitialize,
            INITIALIZE_DEADLINE_NAME,
            InitializeEvent.builder()
                .id(event.getId())
                .build()
        );
    }

    @DeadlineHandler(deadlineName = INITIALIZE_DEADLINE_NAME)
    protected void onDeadline(final InitializeEvent command) {
        this.commandGateway.send(command);
    }

    // ...
}
```

I've abstracted away the non-relevant code. Keep in mind that nowhere else in the codebase we modify the `StdScheduler` instance injected as a Bean dependency for `DeadlineManager`.

However, when executing my code, I keep getting the following Exception:

```
2020-05-28 03:26:13.001 ERROR 1 --- [eduler_Worker-1] o.a.deadline.quartz.DeadlineJob          : Exception occurred during processing a deadline job which will be retried [com.eblock.simulcast.bidding_engine_axon.auction_event.command.InitializeAuctionEvent]

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar!/:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1608) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar!/:5.4.15.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.updateSaga(JpaSagaStore.java:272) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.updateSaga(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:208) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.commit(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:174) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.lambda$doLoad$2(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:121) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.MessageProcessingContext.notifyHandlers(MessageProcessingContext.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.DefaultUnitOfWork.notifyHandlers(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:106) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.changePhase(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:222) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commitAsRoot(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:83) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commit(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.DefaultUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:92) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.UnitOfWork.executeWithResult(UnitOfWork.java:328) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.deadline.quartz.DeadlineJob.execute(DeadlineJob.java:134) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar!/:na]

2020-05-28 03:26:13.001  INFO 1 --- [eduler_Worker-1] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell              : Job InitializeAuctionEvent.deadline-7e5d9eec-2c7d-4312-9dde-acb9a56abc6b threw a JobExecutionException: 

org.quartz.JobExecutionException: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.axonframework.deadline.quartz.DeadlineJob.execute(DeadlineJob.java:143) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) ~[quartz-2.3.2.jar!/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar!/:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1608) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar!/:5.4.15.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy175.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.jpa.JpaSagaStore.updateSaga(JpaSagaStore.java:272) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.updateSaga(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:208) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.commit(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:174) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.modelling.saga.repository.AnnotatedSagaRepository.lambda$doLoad$2(AnnotatedSagaRepository.java:121) ~[axon-modelling-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.MessageProcessingContext.notifyHandlers(MessageProcessingContext.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.DefaultUnitOfWork.notifyHandlers(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:106) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.changePhase(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:222) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commitAsRoot(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:83) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.AbstractUnitOfWork.commit(AbstractUnitOfWork.java:71) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.DefaultUnitOfWork.executeWithResult(DefaultUnitOfWork.java:92) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.messaging.unitofwork.UnitOfWork.executeWithResult(UnitOfWork.java:328) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    at org.axonframework.deadline.quartz.DeadlineJob.execute(DeadlineJob.java:134) ~[axon-messaging-4.3.3.jar!/:4.3.3]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
```

I decided to debug and spend a few hours trying to narrow down the issue. I realized that somehow outside of my codebase (likely Axon magic), the `StdScheduler.getContext().get(DeadlineJob.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_KEY)` gets overridden.

Here are 2 screenshots that highlight the issue:

[image]

As you can see, the instance number of `StdScheduler` 13137 contains the `SpringTransactionManager` during initialize().

When I add the breakpoint straight on my scheduling line, here is the screenshot:

[image]

Instance of `StdScheduler` is still 13137, and the `QuartzDeadlineManager.transactionManager` still contains an instance of `SpringTransactionManager`. But the `StdScheduler.getContext().get(DeadlineJob.TRANSACTION_MANAGER_KEY)` now contains a `NoTransactionManager` instance, which then causes my execution to break due to a `TransactionRequiredException`.

Did anyone experience this scenario? How was it mitigated? Right now I'm traversing through all Axon code in an attempt to understand where the instance gets swapped.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not an Axon expert, but using standard scheduler, you can (and in my opinion should) dispatch a command to your aggregate instead of directly firing an aggregate event. You can go with `SagaEvent` -> `AggregateCommand` -> `AggregateEvent` order. But again, I am not an expert, never used DeadLines so far. Also, I don't understand if your `InitializeEvent` is and event or command.

Comment: Sorry Alper, the "Event" is my actual Aggregate... in that scenario it is a command.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out the issue.
In my `AxonConfiguration` class, the method for `EventScheduler` was left there in case we had to revert or use that scheduler in a near future.
The `EventScheduler` was defined as this:

```
    @Bean
    public QuartzEventSchedulerFactoryBean eventScheduler() {
        return new QuartzEventSchedulerFactoryBean();
    }
```

As the `QuartzEventScheduler` was created by the FactoryBean, it was pulling the `StdScheduler` from the `ApplicationContext`, and assigning the relevant variables all over again. Since I had no customized `TransactionManager`, the default (`NoTransactionManager`) was being assigned to the `QuartzEventScheduler`, which then changes the `QuartzScheduler` context, causing the issue.

To fix that, I expanded my Bean to the following:

```
    @Bean
    public QuartzEventSchedulerFactoryBean eventScheduler(
        final ApplicationContext applicationContext,
        @Qualifier("eventStore") final EventBus eventBus,
        final Scheduler scheduler,
        final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager
    ) {
        final QuartzEventSchedulerFactoryBean factoryBean = new QuartzEventSchedulerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        factoryBean.setEventBus(eventBus);
        factoryBean.setScheduler(scheduler);
        factoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        factoryBean.setTransactionDefinition(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());

        return factoryBean;
    }
```

---

**Here is my ask for the Axon team:**

The `QuartzEventScheduler(FactoryBean)` requires the underlying `PlatformTransactionManager`, and creates a new `SpringTransactionManager` to assign. It would be much easier if they kept the same approach as `QuartzDeadlineManager`, using directly an autowired `TransactionManager`, instead of handling the instantiation internally (and replacing the axon-spring-autoconfigure created one).

Comment: This is a discrepancy between the `EventScheduler` solution (introduced in Axon 0.7) and the `DeadlineManager` (introduced in Axon 3.3), which definitely slipped our notice. Our apologies for the inconvenience it caused, although I am happy to notice you resolved it quickly regardless. We are planning a rather thorough update on the `axon-spring` module already, I've added this pointer to the list as well.